# What are the differences between these two ways of starting threads?

Tags: java, concurrency, multithreading

If I have a class that implements the Runnable interface, what are the differences between these statements in the main method?

```
MyThread t1 = new MyThread();
t1.start();
```

and

```
MyThread t2 = new MyThread();
new Thread(t2).start();
```

Comment: Runnable interface does not have a start() method, so your first call would fail.

Comment: But that doesn't look like an implemented Runnable-interface, but like an extended Thread-class.

Comment: "If I have a class that implements the Runnable interface ..."

Answer (score 1):

Since you did `t1.start()`, I assume MyThread extends Thread. In this case, the first one is correct.

The second create a new thread, then start the task in yet another thread. One thread is wasted.

Comment: no thread is wasted. a new thread is only created when calling start(), and that is called only once either way...

Answer (score 1):

To implement a thread in Java you basically have two options. One: you extend the class Thread and implement the method run. That seems to be the case with your example. In that case you should call the start()-method of your Thread.class. That is variant one of the two you provided.

The second variant is if you implement the Runnable-interface. In that case you also implement the method run, but your class doesn't have a start, so you create a new Thread-class with your Runnable as a parameter (as you did in your second example). But that doesn't make sense, if you already extended Thread.

I personally prefer to implement Runnable, because I don't change the behaviour of Thread (that would be extending it), but only use the Thread-functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that

```
class MyThread extends Thread
```

Your first call starts your code in a new thread.

The call

```
new Thread(new MyThread()).start();
```

will too run your code in MyThread, as the Thread constructor only needs an object implementing the Runnable interface and the run() method. Your MyThread class already has this method so it will be executed by the simple wrapper thread. Note also that your new MyThread remains basically an unstarted thread.

You could try the following small program:

```
public class MyThread extends Thread {
    public void run() {
        if (Thread.currentThread() != this) {
            System.out.println("Wrapped into a separate thread");
            start();
        } else {
            System.out.println("MyThread run as expected");
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Thread(new MyThread ()).start();
    }
}
```

To make it less confusing due the names lets have a look at another example:

```
public class MyJPanel extends JPanel implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Hello MyJPanel");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Thread(new MyJPanel()).start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first call (if it would be a run()) would execute in the current Thread, while the second one would create a new thread that would run the run() method of your Runnable.

Comment: But he didn't call run(), he called start().

Answer (score 0):

in second one you create a new thread that you dont hold in a variable and start this new thread. t2 remains same.

in first one you create t1 and start...

i think, second is meaningless

Answer (score 0):

Whenever your class has to extend another class, use Runnable.

And Runnable interface includes only run method not start.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `MyThread` only implements the `Runnable` interface, the second code snippet is the correct pattern to use.  `Thread.start()` chains to a native method that will drum up a new thread.  It will then call its own `run()`, which will call `run()` on its instance `Runnable` variable.  In your second code snippet, this would be an instance of `MyThread`, your `Runnable`.

The first code snippet, given the information you have provided, will not compile, unless:

- you have implemented a `start` method on your own.  If this is the case, your code will not drum up a new thread and you will only follow the process in the current thread as is defined in your `MyThread.start()`.
- you have actually extended `Thread` as well as implementing `Runnable`.  If this is the case, the `Runnable` interface is redundant, as `Thread` also implements this interface.  Also, you should be careful if you are overriding the `start` method, as a call to super is needed if you want to drum up a new thread.  For this reason at least, it is good to have a class only implement `Runnable` and not exend `Thread`.  Further, if you are only implementing `Runnable`, it would be best not to use the word `Thread` in the name.

Answer (score 0):

> MyThread t1 = new MyThread();  t1.start();

will be compile time exception

> MyThread t2 = new MyThread(); new Thread(t2).start();

will be working fine.runnable interface is not having start method.